# Guardar informação sobre dias de execução

Tags: sql, desempenho, data

Boa tarde, pessoal. Tenho um sistema de monitoramento de automações que consome uma tabela que contém informações sobre n automações cadastradas, cerca de 40 atualmente. Gostaria no entanto de fazer um controle sobre os dias os quais essas automações irão rodar. Exemplo: Automação 1 roda apenas segunda a sexta, automação 2 roda também aos sábados e domingos, etc.
Para não fazer essas regras diretamente no código estava pensando em fazer uma tabela de dias da semana e liga-la como chave estrangeira a tabela em que estão as automações. Minha dúvida é: Essa é a melhor forma? Como vocês fariam a tabela? estava pensando em fazer uma tabela com id e os dias da semana booleanos e então tratar isso no fonte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia amigo,

Nas empresas que eu já trabalhei tanto como desenvolvedor quanto outras funções, é comum a prática de realizar um cadastro de escala de trabalho do equipamento, que no seu caso chamaremos de escala de automações, onde você define quais os dias da semana aquela aplicação vai rodar aquela aplicação ou entao uma configuracao de escalas em geral. Caso sua rotina mude, você altera apenas essa escala para aquele equipamento específico ou só altera a escala geral e deixe que o sistema faça o cálculo dos dias. Em adição voce pode criar um cadastro de feriado caso use como ressesso, para que ele calcule a não automação nestes dias também.

Qualquer dúvida estou a disposição!

Comment: como é esse cadastro de escala?
é um id | seg | ter | qua | qui | sex | sab e ai vocês deixam marcos os dias? é feito no bd mesmo?

Comment: Ai já depende de como você prefere trabalhar e tratar os dias da semana, mas sim, geralmente são checks que voce marga de seg à dom.

Comment: entendi, beleza, obrigado ;)